# how to run a application in opensaf

Tags: opensaf

I am new to opensaf and want a sample code to run.
So please help me to run a small code by sending me the procedure to install opensaf and execute a program.
I am like a baby in opensaf so don't mind to send even small steps

Comment: Have you already read http://sourceforge.net/p/opensaf/wiki/Home/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Look for samples in your opensaf release. You will need a basic understanding of SAF and High availability concepts to use opensaf. Post a message to the opensaf-users mailing list for help.